# Exponential and Natural Log Power Series

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, formal-power-series

I am asked to prove $$e^{Y\log(1+Z)} = (1+Z)^Y$$ using power series definitions for both the exponential function and natural log.  I am really stumped on this.  Our hunt was using the nth derivative of the power series $e^{Y\log(1+Z)}$ and determine the coefficient on $Z^n$ but I am really stumped.  Please help

Comment: Hint: Prove that $D(e^{Y\log(1+Z)})=e^{Y\log(1+Z)}\frac{\alpha}{1+Z}$, where D is the differential-operator. The answer then follows due to the unique solution of the ODE.

Comment: Okay so I did that but solving that differential equation makes use of the identity I’m trying to prove doesn’t it?

Comment: I guess is it okay to prove it that way I thought that would be a little hand wavy

Comment: You can now argue that $(exp^{-1}){'}x=1/\exp{'}((exp^{-1})x)=1/x=log(x){'}$ where log is your power-series and and $exp^{-1}$ is the inverse function to the exp powerseries

Answer (score 4):

$e^z=1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+...$ therefore $\frac{de^Z}{dz}=1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+...=e^z$.

$\log (1+z)=z-\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^3}{3}-...  $ therefore $\frac{d \log(1+z)}{dz}=1-z+z^2-...=\frac{1}{1+z}$.

Then 
$$\frac{d}{dZ}(e^{Y\log(1+Z)})=(e^{Y\log(1+Z)})\frac{Y}{1+Z}$$
and 
$$\frac{d}{dZ}(1+Z)^Y=(1+Z)^Y\frac{Y}{1+Z}.$$

By the quotient rule we then see that  $\frac{e^{Y\log(1+Z)}}{(1+Z)^Y}$ has zero derivative and is therefore constant. Substitution of $Z=0$ shows that this constant is $1$ and therefore $$e^{Y\log(1+Z)} = (1+Z)^Y.$$

Comment: What part of the quotient rule are you using

Comment: The numerator of the derivative of $u/v$ is $u'v-v'u$ and this is zero for the function in question.

Comment: I see now I apologize I was on a flight trying to do math in my head without much focus thank you.